# How do I remove my Facebook account from Gwibber?

Tags: 12.10, settings, gwibber, facebook

I started using Ubuntu 12.10 today, and put in my social networking details in Online Accounts under System Settings.
I like being able to chat with my Facebook friends in Empathy, but I don't necessarily want my tweets to go to Facebook. I want to remove Facebook from Gwibber, but not Empathy. How do I do this? There is nothing in Gwibber preferences and I can't see how to do it in Online Accounts.
The reason I want to remove it is that it isn't clear enough which accounts are posted to and I don't necessarily want the feeds mixing together.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can delete the package `gwibber-service-facebook`.
To do this just run terminal and execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gwibber-service-facebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I recently asked the same question on G+, and this is the answer I received:

'sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop

Go into startup applications and uncheck gwibber'

Hope that helps.

Comment: This looks like it's about removing Gwibber itself. That's not what I want to do.